# Why weierstrass equation should not be used for elliptic curves over the field char=2?

Tags: extension-field, elliptic-curves, singularity

According to my source, this is because 'Weierstrass equation is singular', and it shows singularity by the point $(x_0,y_0)$, where $x_0$ is the root of $-3x^2-A$(maybe on a field extension), and $y_0$ satisfies $y_0^2=x_0^3+Ax+B$. He claims the derivatives $f_x(x_0,y_0)=f_y(x_0,y_0)=0$ by using char=2. \
But this still does not make sense to me, why we care about a derivate of point on a field extension? \
For derivates, my guess is that zero derivatives implies multiple roots, which weierstrass equation not allowed(but I also dont know why not). But as I said above, $(x_0,y_0)$ may be a point out of our initial field, why we care?

Comment: You want a *smooth curve*.  There are many theorems about smooth curves that are false for singular (non-smooth) curves. Have you read proofs of geometric theorems about smooth curves?  Typically they involve working over algebraically closed fields, even if you might be more interested in points with coordinates in a smaller field.

Comment: The point is that you cannot use the **short** Weierstrass form in characteristics two or three. You should use **the Weierstrass form**
$$y^2+a_1xy+a_3y=x^3+a_2x^2+a_4x+a_6.$$ In characteristic two we can arrange $a_2$ to vanish (but cannot do the same to $a_1$ and $a_3$). In characteristic three we cannot do anything about $a_2$, but can arrange $a_1=0=a_3$.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the problem is the discriminant. By definition, an elliptic curve
**must** have non-zero discriminant, otherwise it is degenerate. A clear
explanation of this with examples of finite fields by John D. Cook is at
[All elliptic curves over fields of order 2 and 3](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2019/03/11/elliptic-curves-gf2-gf3/). With the short Weierstrass form
$\,y^2 = x^3 + Ax + B\,$ there are **no** curves with non-zero discriminant
in a field of characteristic $2$.

The article by Cook makes an important point:

> The two curves in the example of Lendstra and Pila are the only ones
> over GF(2) with five points. So the two curves of order 5 over GF(2) are
>
> $$y^2 + y = x^3 + x^2$$
> $$y^2 + y = x^3 + x.$$
>
> They determine the same set of points but are algebraically different.

He explains what this means with

> Both determine the same set of points, but the two curves are algebraically different because $(0,0) + (0,0)$ equals $(1,1)$ on the first curve and $(1,0)$ on the second.

If the curve is degenerate, then you can't even define the addition of
points on the curve.